# customSignupForm code to allow signup for only the invited user

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I am developing a feature where the user has to request for invitation if he/she wants to sign up on the site. When the request is accepted by the admin, the user gets to sign up, otherwise it shows them an error saying they are not invited at this time, and saves a email so we can follow up with him/her. To be generic, I used the condition `INVITE_MODE = True` in settings, so if we disable the invitation feature using `INVITE_MODE=False`, all the users should get to sign up.

Here is my signup form and I am using Django allauth for that:

```
class CustomSignupForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomSignupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        print ('email', email)
        email = get_adapter().clean_email(email)
        # if email and app_settings.UNIQUE_EMAIL:
        #     email = self.validate_unique_email(email)
        if email and settings.INVITE_MODE:
            try:
                Invitation.objects.get(email=email, request_approved=True)
            except Invitation.DoesNotExist:
                invitation, created = Invitation.objects.get_or_create(email=email)
                self.add_error('email', 'Sorry at this time you are not invited. But we have added you to our invite list')
        elif email is None:
            self.add_error('email', 'Email field cannot be empty')
        else:
            return email


    def signup(self, request, user):
        # email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        # user.email = email
        user.save()
```

Can anyone suggest a to do this in a better/efficient way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good motivation to overwrite the Form's `clean()` method is when you need to modify/check multiple fields ([reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/validation/)):

> The form subclass’s `clean()` method can perform validation that
>   requires access to multiple form fields. This is where you might put
>   in checks such as “if field A is supplied, field B must contain a
>   valid email address”.

And, the overwritten `clean()` method usually returns the modified `cleaned_data`.

In your case, you only work with a *single field*, use the `clean_<fieldname>()` method - `clean_email()` to be specific.

I would also handle the "email is falsy" case beforehand (though, I am not completely sure if you actually need to worry about it here and having `required=True` on your email form field is not enough).

Also, I'm not sure you actually need to call `clean_email()` on the adapter - if you are using the default account adapter, I think it is doing nothing and is simply a "stub" for custom adapters ([source](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/4bb9e0170f37d8196bd0c4a78e83adb7b779c113/allauth/account/adapter.py#L175)).

I think using `get_or_create()` first and then checking the `request_approved` value could be a bit cleaner.

Here is a variation of the code with applied assumptions and suggestions (described above):

```
def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data.get['email']

    if settings.INVITE_MODE:
        invitation, _ = Invitation.objects.get_or_create(email=email)
        if not invitation.request_approved:
            self.add_error('email', 'Sorry at this time you are not invited. But we have added you to our invite list')

    return email
```

One concern with that though - I am not sure if creating an invitation record from a form field's clean form method is a good thing and is not a sign of a bad design..

Another note is that if a new user would submit the form multiple times with the same email address, the user would get the same "Sorry at this time you are not invited. But we have added you to our invite list" message. Instead, may be, if email does not exist, you can say that the user was added to the invite list, but if email exists but the invitation is not approved, you can say something more specific, like "Your invitation is waiting for approval".

Comment: Thanks @alecxe for informative solution with good explanation. However i did not understand where should i handle creating invitation record if he/she tries to signup without requesting for invitation.

Comment: Also I am confused because of multiple condition like if INVITE_MODE is True then only check for invitation request otherwise do normal signup process and another condition is to check if email exists and requested email is approved or not. Now another check that is if email does not exist, show The user was added to the invite list. (now do i have to check using if not invitation, self.add_error('email', 'The user was added to the invite list')) ?

Comment: @pythonLover I was, of course, hoping to confuse you :) I don't have enough Django experience to answer the first question - I've just noted that there is a potential "separation of concerns" and "design" problem. I'd resolve the other confusion you have with handling all of these cases separately and provide custom error messages - this might be clearer for an end user and would also be more explicit and easier to test. Thanks and sorry if I've confused you even more - hope that helps as at least an another look onto the problem.

Comment: I got the separation and design concept. Regarding the custom error message, can you just make me clear a bit with pseudocode if not django specific? The error message of you were talking about where multiple ifs will be used to check.

Comment: @pythonLover I think it's just 3 cases we need to cover: there is no invitation, there is one but unapproved and there is one but approved.  You can cover the "there is an invitation but not approved" by checking the created flag of the result of `get_or_create()` call to be False. Hope this is a bit clearer. Thanks.

Comment: Yes i understand you. Also i have marked it as solved. Thanks again for knowledge.